# How can I resolve the 10007 - "permission denied" PayPal API error using the paypal-express gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm using the [paypal-express](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express) gem in my ruby on rails project. I want users to be able to purchase digital goods on my web application. I've created a controller with a new and create action. The `new` action generates a PayPal link which users visit. Users are returned from PayPal to the `create` action where I attempt to complete the order.

Everything works fine in development when using sandbox credential, when using production credentials I receive a "10007 - permission denied" error from PayPal.

I have triple checked the username/password/API signature i've entered for production and they are correct (The user is sent to the correct PayPal store).

Here is my controller:

```
class DigitalPaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [ :new, :create ]

  def new
    Paypal.sandbox! unless Rails.env.production?

    response = paypal_request.setup(
      payment_request,
      success_url,
      cancel_url,
      :no_shipping => true
    )

    @paypal_url = response.redirect_uri
  end

  def create
    begin
      response = paypal_request.checkout!(params[:token], params[:PayerID], payment_request)

      if response.payment_info.first.payment_status == 'Completed'
        # TODO: Handle complete payments
      else
        # TODO: Handle non complete payments
      end
    rescue Paypal::Exception::APIError => e
      # Payment has failed, failure details are in e.message, also check params
    end
  end

  private

  def paypal_request
    @request ||= Paypal::Express::Request.new(
      :username   => PAYPAL_USERNAME,
      :password   => PAYPAL_PASSWORD,
      :signature  => PAYPAL_SIGNATURE
    )
  end

  def payment_request
    @payment_request ||= Paypal::Payment::Request.new(
      :currency_code => :USD,
      :amount => 15,
      :items => [{
      :name => "Awesome Product",
      :description => 'Description of awesomeness',
      :amount => 15,
      :category => :Digital
    }]
    )
  end
end
```

Having a look into the paypal-express gem, it seems to call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` on the PayPal API and pass the PayerID and the Token. The PayPal API documentation didn't list a way to resolve my error (10007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the PayPal API error was that i needed to call the PayPal `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` action before checking out the transaction. I did this by adding a line from the paypal-express gem wiki over here: https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/wiki/Instant-Payment

All I needed was `paypal_request.details(params[:token])`